# Want to find the degrees with the cosine similarity value

Tags: python

Suppose, I am getting 0.87456 as a cosine value through cosine function in python language.
I want to know the degree to plot in X-Y plane graph? How can I get the value in degrees.

Answer (score 3):

I just did the following test and I believe it to be correct:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.degrees(math.acos(0.87456))
29.007055526563033
```

So, as you can see, the `math` library contains `acos` (for inverse cosine) and `degrees` (for converting radians to degrees).

Comment: @JatinChopra. You're welcome. Please accept my answer, so it can be used as a reference.